# Replace nbsp with another tag

Tags: xslt-2.0

In my xml file I have a tag like this(within the p tags I have nbsp;)

Now I want to replace this nbsp with another tag(as an example within p tag I want to insert another tag called s `<s/>`)

Is this possible to do.Please help

Answer (score 0):

First note that the tree on which XSLT operates never contains a character or entity reference, it simply contains an Unicode character. To match on and replace an Unicode character with an element you can use `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p//text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#160;">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <s/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way an input document like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<doc>
  <p>This is a paragraph with a non-breaking space &nbsp; before some sub text.</p>
</doc>
```

is transformed into the result document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><doc>
  <p>This is a paragraph with a non-breaking space <s/> before some sub text.</p>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you.It works for me.Can we do the same thing for any character entity.

Comment: You can change the `regex` attribute of the `analyze-string` to match more or other characters. As I said, that construct matches on characters, not on entity references or character references. Whether the original XML input contained an entity reference or character reference or a character literally is not stored in the tree data structure XSLT operates on.